# Bluray LightScribe drive slowly dying - any recommended fixes?

Tags: drivers, dvd, repair, lightscribe, diagnostic

I'm getting sporadically functioning Bluray drive in my HP DV5T laptop.  Anybody have any ideas that I could use to get it working again, short of replacing it?  Here is the history I tried with it today:

> Lightscribe Blu-ray player not working
>   anymore: Model: HL-DT-ST BDDVDRW CT10L
>
> Type: DVD/CD-ROM drives
>
> Tried putting blank CD-R ... not
>   recognized Tried using MS Visio
>   software ... not recognized Installing
>   new driver from LightScribe.
>
> Windows being used to write to a
>   lightscribe disk... now it seems to
>   work... but the Windows SW is weak and
>   slow -- doesn't report time remaining.
>   When it does, it reports a rediculous
>   1 hour 32 minutes.  (started at
>   10:10AM). Next will try the
>   Power-to-go software option.
>
> Trying to install 10:38:00 AM
>   1/19/2011 Visio once again ... lots of
>   clicking sounds... still not reading
>   from the disk.
>
> Going back and trying the disk I JUST
>   burned. 10:40:15  The newly burned
>   disk is NOT WORKING EITHER! ! !
>
> Going to burn a label onto the disk...
>   for what its worth.
>
> 10:46 AM 1/19/2011 Drive E: Detecting
>   Media. Please wait...   <---
>   Lightscribe template SW
>
> 11:00 AM 1/19/2011 Plese but a
>   lightscribe disk in LABEL DOWN ....
>   OK, I do it, for the second time...
>   11:06 AM 1/19/2011 Damn thing is stuck
>   on the 'estimating' step at 0% 11:12
>   AM 1/19/2011 Crappy DVD... must be
>   totally broken.
>
> "The disc in the LightScribe drive is
>   not recognized"... please ensure blah
>   blah blah 11:13 AM 1/19/2011 TRY AGAIN
>
> ...around 11:17, I succeed, after 7-8
>   tries, to get MS Visio to install.
>
> Subsequent attempts to use the
>   LightScribe feature, though, don't
>   work.

Comment: Please update the question with your OS version.

Comment: Vista 64-bit is my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Find the driver from the manufacturer of the drive (not Lightscribe) and if/once you do, completely uninstall the drivers for the drive. Once they are uninstalled, install the drivers that you downloaded (or if you have the disc) and try burning/reading disks again.

Remember, Lightscribe drivers and the drivers for your Blu ray drive are different and not related at all. You don't need the Lightscribe drivers to read/write discs, just to write labels with LIghtscribe software.

Note: If you have Windows 7, you can let it try to find the proper drivers for you.